# Generating +/- voltages for biasing an opamp using a digipot

Tags: digital-potentiometer, offset

I am trying to generate a programmable bias voltage for a non-inverting opamp using a digital POT with an up/down interface as putting a micro in the circuit is not feasible.

I have come across a wide variety of digipots from Analog Deivces, Texas Instruments and Maxim Integrated, but almost 99% of them are designed for single supply operation (0-5 V.)

Can I use a single supply digipot to generate + & - reference voltages? The output voltage range would have to be within -100 to +100 mV.

Am I right in thinking that if I power the digipot from 5 V and step down the voltage applied to the POT end terminals to +/- 1 V (the -1 V generated for a separate -ve PSU) I can put a resistor divider (10) to generate the +/-100 mV?

Please see the circuit attached.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiX7Bt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Am I right in thinking that as long as the voltage across the terminals are within 5 V, the polarity of the voltage won't matter? Is this possible?

Comment: Most excellent follow up question to your previous one! +1

Answer (score 0):

As long as the voltages on the pins don't exceed the abs. max ratings it's fine.

Note that some low-pin-count digipots have only a single WIPER terminal which means that the pot is between WIPER and GND. Since the GND is the same GND as supply GND, it's obvious that this type of digipots cannot be used in your application.

5V models are, generally, not negative-voltage-tolerant *(and I don't know if there's any negative-voltage-tolerant digipot)* so care must be taken. Judging from the schematic, even if a digipot having isolated terminals is used, I can see that the bottom end of the pot will see a voltage below supply GND. This might create some trouble because the chip will be running outside the guaranteed limits.

PS: I hope that you aware of the fact that the op amp's non-inverting input will see a few microvolts which is waaaay less than the offset error of the op amp, even if the output voltage of your digitally-controlled bias generator outputs 5V (seems impossible but let's assume for a moment).

Answer (score 0):

Generally that's not true. There are protection networks and maybe diffusion isolation diodes that will conduct with negative voltages.

They generally expect both ends of the 'element' and the wiper to remain within the power supply voltages. Take, for example, the Microchip [MCP4xxx series](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/268/MCHPS02708_1-2520528.pdf). Absolute maximum is -0.3 to Vdd +0.3 (or limit the current to +/-20mA). That's not something you want to get too close to, because the leakage in the Vf of the diodes will affect your voltage in the first case (especially at elevated temperatures), and because reliability may be affected in the second. But 300mV >> 100mV.

So you might well be able to allow -100mV and use a cheap digipot. The +100mV, of course, is no problem.

Note that (in general) I would tend to use lower value resistors for R1 and R2 and parallel the element with a fixed resistor of an order of magnitude or more less in resistance to tame any large temperature coefficient the element may have (and reduce the effect of leakage). Digital pots are typically better or much better when used in potentiometer mode. Eg. 20k, 20k and 1.1k 1%.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had in mind on your previous question. Please note that this is a low effort 2 minute hack. I'm sure plenty of optimization and simplification is possible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sending this schematic. 
does this mean that the digipot can be used with a a single supply and the 200k  & 10k resistors connected to the -5V line is used as an offset? In other words, the whole system is wired as a summer?

Comment: @Labmat Yes until the word summer. What does that mean in this regard?

Comment: what I was trying to say was that this config looks like a summing amplifier. 
So can you please explain how would I set the system up?
Say for example, I needed 10uV output voltage, 
1. set the lower bound voltage (-)ve value (say -20uV)
2. Set the digipot to give 30uV.
3. Set the gain of the system to be unity gain
4. Output would equal 10uV

I know that this is talking in the ideal world and in the practical world this may need quite a bit of tweaking.
did I get this right?

Comment: Oh oh oh! Summer. Yes, exactly. If you have a varying output voltage from your digipot and a fixed one from a negative supply, you can sum them with a _summer_ and by tweaking the values, have your desired +-100 mV from a positive only digipot. But what happened to your 100 mV which to need now down to 100 uV? Opamps in general are not good at that. If you can live with some output impedance, you can divide the output down. That or specialized opamp for uV levels of drift and perhaps even offset.

Comment: I was thinking that in order to get down to the uV level, I could change the Opamp feedback resistor so that it acts as an attenuator rather than an amplifier. 
Alternatively, because the output of  this circuit is going into the non inverting pin of the Opamp,  I could divide the output voltage (from the digipot circuitry) by 1000 (using a basic resistor voltage divider) and then feed that to the non-inverting pin of the inverting opamp.??

I know that the second suggestion would work as I have tried  it out on the existing circuitry.

Comment: @LabMat Go for it! Report back your findings.

Comment: I've done some simulations and this is what I have come up with @winny [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNPXL.png) This would give me a range of approx. -100uV - +100uV. Please note that this is using the opamp as an attenuator (divide by 1000). What do you think? Thanks

Comment: Many opamps are not unity gain stable, but there should be those out there which will do your +-100 uV. Drift and offset comes to mind. As someone said previously, if this is a concern there are chopper stabilized ones but you may need low pass on the output.